# Acces a model/class attribute by filtering fields

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass a row from my database by doing:

```
def index(request):
    current_user = request.user
    username = User.objects.get(username=current_user.username)
    listing = Listing.objects.filter(owner=username).all()
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
    "listing":listing
    })
```

But if then i try to access by doing `listing.title` I get the following error:
`'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'`

How could I access listing.title? I only want the row where `owner=username`

Comment: `listing` is a *collection* of `Listing` objects, not a single object, hence using `.title` makes no sense.

Comment: How would I access that field?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change .all() for .first()